# Find a file efficiently of which I know the sub path but not the root folder

Tags: powershell

I'm making a build file in Powershell. This build file needs to reference the Visual Studio 2017 version of MSBuild.exe. Unfortunately the path to that file depends on the edition of Visual Studio you have installed.

For example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Pro\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
```

Of course I can use

```
$partial = ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} + '\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\'
Get-ChildItem -Path $partial -Filter 'MsBuild.exe' -Recurse
```

But there are a lot of other files and folders under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\`.

Unfortunately something like this doesn't work:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $partial -Filter '\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MsBuild.exe' -Recurse
```

Is there a way I can give PowerShell a better hint where to look for MsBuild.exe?

Comment: I would suggest that maybe you could search once and then cache the answer somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps a registry key with the installed path?

Comment: To expand on Mark's comment, the [uninstall key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx) likely holds that information. Just be careful for 32/64 bitness as the values also exist in `WOW6432Node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-childitem support wildcards. As only a specific part of the string changes (pro / community) you could replace that with a wildcard.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\*\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
```

In fact you can just use get-item the full wildcard path.

```
Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\*\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
```

This will return any and all files matching and assuming each user only have one installed version of Visual Studio, you will get one file.

Comment: Thanks, I had no clue. This is exactly the solution I hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this, and add where for select your version of msbuild

```
Resolve-Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\* | 
Get-ItemProperty | select MSBuildToolsPath
```

Comment: This looked promising, but it seems that MSBuild 15 is not registered under that registry key.